# textFieldShouldReturn does not get called (textField loaded programmatically)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I'm currently loading a -`UITextField` programmatically and trying to make the keyboard go down once I click on 'Search'.

I declare the `-UITextFeild` inside the .m file as 
`UITextField *searchTextField;`

Inside the .h file I do indeed declare the `-UITextField`'s delegate

```
@interface firstChannel : UIViewController<LBYouTubePlayerControllerDelegate, UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource, NSXMLParserDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate, AVPlayerItemOutputPullDelegate>{
```

This is how I add the UITextField programmatically.

```
 searchTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, -26, 300, 30)];
    searchTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    searchTextField.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Heiti TC" size:13];
    searchTextField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
    searchTextField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
    searchTextField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
    searchTextField.placeholder = @"Search on the Channel";
    searchTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;;
    searchTextField.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    searchTextField.center = CGPointMake(160, 43);
    searchTextField.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(232.0/255.0) green:(232.0/255.0) blue:(232.0/255.0) alpha:(100.0/100.0)];
    searchTextField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeNever;
    searchTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeySearch;
    [searchTextField setKeyboardAppearance:UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert];
    [self.view.window addSubview:searchTextField];
    [searchTextField becomeFirstResponder];
```

I added the delegate inside `-viewDidLoad`

```
searchTextField.delegate = self;
```

However when I click on "Search" on the keyboard nothing happens. I'm unsure why that's happening I've even debugged it by logging something once you hit returns but nothing happens.

Comment: You never set the text field's `delegate`.

Comment: I forgot to mention that inside -viewDidLoad I did add searchTextField.delegate = self;

Comment: are you using UITextfield or UISeachBar

Comment: @GretarAgnarsson Is the call to `searchTExtField.delegate` made before or after you create and setup the text field? Make sure it is done after.

Comment: I was calling it before the textField was created, I called it now after it was created and it works, thanks @rmaddy

Comment: Post the correct answer so that others can get the solution @Gretar Agnarsson

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call the `searchTExtField.delegate` after you create and setup the text field.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving all the code in viewDidLoad

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad]; searchTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, -26, 300, 30)];
        searchTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
        searchTextField.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Heiti TC" size:13];
        searchTextField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
        searchTextField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
        searchTextField.delegate = self;
        searchTextField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
        searchTextField.placeholder = @"Search on the Channel";
        searchTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;;
        searchTextField.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
        searchTextField.center = CGPointMake(160, 43);
        searchTextField.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(232.0/255.0) green:(232.0/255.0) blue:(232.0/255.0) alpha:(100.0/100.0)];
        searchTextField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeNever;
        searchTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeySearch;
        [searchTextField setKeyboardAppearance:UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert];
        [self.view.window addSubview:searchTextField];
        [searchTextField becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

Also, if you are using search bar then you need to use search bar delegate. If you are just using UITextfield, then you should be okay.

Answer (score 0):

Have you implemented the delegate method (this method gets called when the user taps the return key):

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
   [textField resignFirstResponder];
   //Perform search with text:
   [self performSearch:[textField text]];
   return NO;
}
```

This will resign the responder. Here you can also call your search method.